# SwiftUI How to align the bottom of two text with different font size?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I’m trying to align the bottom of two Text but the larger one looks like this[my widget looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ABAf.jpg). I don’t know why there’s still some space below this Text view.
This is my code:

```
var body: some View {
GeometryReader{geometry in
    ZStack(alignment: .center){
        Image("background")
            .resizable()
        VStack(){
            HStack(alignment: .bottom){
                Text("3")
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .font(.bold(.system(size: 100))())
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: nil, height: geometry.size.height/3, alignment: .bottom)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .shadow(radius: 2)
                Text("cups")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .shadow(radius: 2)
            }
            Text("Next cup on")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .font(.system(size: 10))
                .shadow(radius: 2)
                .opacity(0.5)
            Text("10 : 00")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .font(.system(size: 12))
                .shadow(radius: 1)
                .opacity(0.5)
        }
    }
}
```

}

What I want is the number 3’s bottom aligned to “cups”’s bottom.
Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of `.bottom`, you can use `.lastTextBaseline` as your `HStack` alignment:

```
HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline) {
    Text("Hello").font(.system(size: 40))
    Text("World").font(.system(size: 10))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I still don’t know why there’s a little more space below the text in that blue rectangle even when I’m using the .lastTextBaseline. It looks well now though, I just want to figure out the reason.

Comment: You'd have to create an example that could be compiled by others for me to check it out.

Comment: Ah -- so it's a second question, dealing with the horizontal alignment?

Comment: It’s just a question derived from the original one. I just want to know the mechanism.

Comment: I don't know -- the only thing that `alignment:` on an `HStack` affects is the vertical alignment. There doesn't *appear* to be a mechanism for affecting that initial horizontal alignment. I will notice that it does not seem to happen if the small text appears first.

Comment: In order to get that issue (which I believe is different) the attention it deserves, I'd encourage you to consider accepting this answer (which answers your original question) and starting a second question about the horizontal alignment issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "there’s a little more space below the text in that blue rectangle"? There are two different texts. Are you referring to the fact that the "p" in "cups" extends below?